# ReentrantLock not waiting for lock release

Tags: java, reentrantlock

Why after acquiring lock control is going to second lock.lock() statement? Isin't it should wait indefinitely over 2nd lock statement for acquiring it?

Is it because I am acquiring lock in single thread?

```
   Class LockTest{
        private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();  
        public static void main(String[] args){
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println(lock.isLocked());
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println(lock.isLocked());
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

Comment: What do you think the _Reentrant_ in `ReentrantLock` means?

Comment: Thanks @Pillar the provided link is helpful

Comment: `Isin't it should wait indefinitely over 2nd lock statement for acquiring it` why would you want that?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I m recursively creating multiple thread instances in ThreadPoolExecutor to execute some function and wanted to wait until all the threads are completed before executing the shutdown over executor . So used Lock for waiting indefinitely until it is released..